# Calculate two audio duration with frame

Tags: powershell, logic, duration, calculation

I am stuck, I need a small logic.

I have two audio durations

```
x = "00:00:07:18"
y = "00:00:06:00"        H : M: S: F  
Answer should be x + y = 00:00:13:18
```

H=hours S= seconds M=minutes F=frame

My question is

```
if x = "00:00:03:14"
   y = "00:00:13:18"

answer should be x + y = **00:00:17:02**
```

If the frame is greater than 30 it should increase 1 in second.

I am using power shell. How can I determine the logic to calculate both of this?

Comment: These audio durations - where do they come from? Are they just strings? `[timespan]`'s perhaps?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen tks for your quick replay, yes they are strings, this durations are taken from ffmpeg - ffprobe
i need to add two durations

Comment: Is the frame rate 30 or 31? Asking because of the `:00` frame count in the first example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessenyes its 30 , i have edited the question , sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculation of the first 3 parts (`hour:minute:second`), we can offload to the `[timespan]` type, then all we need to worry about is carrying excess frames over:

```bsh
# Simple helper function to turn our input strings into a [timespan] + frame count
function Parse-FrameDuration
{
    param(
        [string]$Duration
    )

    $hour,$minute,$second,$frame = ($Duration -split ':') -as [int[]]

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time = New-TimeSpan -Hours $hour -Minutes $minute -Seconds $second
        Frame = $frame
    }
}

# function to do the actual calculation
function Add-Frame
{
    param(
        [string]$Base,
        [string]$Offset
    )

    # Parse our two timestamps
    $a = Parse-FrameDuration $Base
    $b = Parse-FrameDuration $Offset

    # Calculate frames % frame rate, remember to carry any excess seconds
    $frames = 0
    $carry = [math]::DivRem($a.Frame + $b.Frame , 30, [ref]$frames)

    # Calculate time difference, add any extra second carried from frame count
    $new = ($a.Time + $b.Time).Add($(New-TimeSpan -Seconds $carry))

    # Stitch output string together from new timespan + remaining frames
    return "{0:hh\:mm\:ss}:{1:00}" -f $new,$frames
}
```

Now we can do:

```
PS C:\> Add-Frame -Base 00:00:03:14 -Offset 00:00:13:18
00:00:17:02
```