# FFMPEG Duration convert To Frames On PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I am new to FFMPEG

I need to get some duration's of some audio and video files.
my out put comes in seconds and milliseconds i guess

I need to convert this milliseconds into frames
FrameCount should be 30

This is my code

```
$audioId = "$id.m4a"
$dur = ffprobe $audioId -show_format 2>&1 | sed -n 's/duration=//p'
echo $dur
```

Output be like, its a loop running

```
3.478042
3.455979
3.522021
```

my question is , i need to keep three seconds as it is , on the right side the milliseconds i need it to be divided by 30

that means i need the answers be like

```
3.15934
3.15199
3.17400
```

thank you

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236204/calculate-two-audio-duration-with-frame/61236768#61236768) should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$audioId = "$id.m4a"
$dur = ffprobe $audioId -show_format 2>&1 | sed -n 's/duration=//p'
Echo ($dur.Split(".")[0] + "." + [math]::Round($dur.Split(".")[1]/30))
```

Comment: No need for `sed`. [`ffprobe` can output the duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604) alone without needing additional parsing tools.